# /etc/environment export path

Tags: linux, centos

I have the following /etc/environment:

```
export PATH=$PATH
```

Whenever I log in I get the following errors:

```
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: tty: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

(my actual /etc/enviroment is more complicated and sets up java onto the path but for simplicity I cant even get the above to work)

I'm using Centos6

Comment: what makes you think the two are related?

Comment: Please could you add more detail. What makes you believe that $PATH had anything useful in before you assigned it to $PATH and exported it?

Comment: @stew because I dont get that error without that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cleaner approach is to use an entry in `/etc/profile.d` over `/etc/environment`, but can you echo the output of $PATH? That may be the real issue. Or at least show the complicated environment file's details.

Comment: Apparently /etc/environment is for system wide variables..https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide%20environment%20variables

Comment: @DD. While that may be the case, CentOS/RHEL may be using it differently. /etc/environment is rather integral to my Ubuntu boxes, but it's an empty file in my stock CentOS units.

Answer (score 7):

You've misunderstood the `/etc/environment` syntax. It's not interpreted as a series of shell commands, so it isn't a `.sh` file at all. The `/etc/environment` is loaded when the shell doesn't exist yet, and when it's still not decided whether there would be `bash` or `csh` or other. There might even be a customization to run some specific program instead of a shell. Hence `/etc/environment` has a really basic syntax.

As seen [on this Unix/Linux StackExchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94551/26411):

> you can only put static environment variable definitions, of the form
>   VARIABLE=VALUE or VARIABLE="VALUE", with one definition per line. You
>   can't have arbitrary shell commands, you can't refer to the value of
>   another variable by writing FOO=hello+$BAR

In your case, you shouldn't have used `export` shell command.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a quoting problem (i.e. the current value of `$PATH` contains IFS characters and bash is trying to execute some part of it). Variable values should almost always be quoted, so that line should look like:

```
export PATH="$PATH"
```

However, since you're not changing the value of `$PATH` you don't actually need the assignment, and the following is sufficient:

```
export PATH
```